# EnterpriseDB Postgres SQL installation failing on Macbook pro 16" M1

Tags: sql, postgresql

#### Summary

I'm attempting to setup pgAdmin 4 along with Postgres SQL on my Mac.

Here's what I've done that results in an error:

1. Download [EnterpriseDB Postgres SQL from here](https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) - postgres SQL version: 14.2 [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads)
2. Run the installer on my machine (See machine specs below)

#### Question:

Can anyone help explain what might be causing this issue? Please note, my Macbook 16 is brand new.

#### Reference:

**Machine Specifications:**

```
Model Name: MacBook Pro
Chip: Apple M1 Pro
Total Number of Cores: 10 (8 performance and 2 efficiency)
Memory: 32 GB
OS: MacOS Monterey 12.2.1
```

**Error received:**

```
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               osx-arm64 [1169]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Desktop/postgresql-14.2-1-osx.app/Contents/MacOS/osx-arm64
Identifier:            osx-arm64
Version:               ???
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Exited process [1166]
User ID:               0

Date/Time:             2022-03-06 10:44:49.1961 +0800
OS Version:            macOS 12.2.1 (21D62)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        BF349008-4102-6C36-452E-5020959FA44F


Time Awake Since Boot: 4000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace OBJC, Code 1 

Application Specific Information:
Invalid or prematurely-freed autorelease pool 0x1431880a8.


Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18162beb8 __abort_with_payload + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18162e864 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 104
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18162e7fc abort_with_reason + 32
3   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1814edd5c _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 120
4   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1814edce4 _objc_fatal(char const*, ...) + 44
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1814ee8e8 AutoreleasePoolPage::badPop(void*) + 212
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1816c5ff8 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 32
7   Foundation                             0x1825ad2ec -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 140
8   AppKit                                 0x18424d9e8 -[NSApplication run] + 648
9   brQEBbHK                               0x107e1aa9c 0x107b48000 + 2960028
10  brQEBbHK                               0x107c40ed8 0x107b48000 + 1019608
11  brQEBbHK                               0x107e6b994 0x107b48000 + 3291540
12  brQEBbHK                               0x107b500c8 RunQAppCmd + 92
13  osx-arm64                              0x10269aa8c 0x102688000 + 76428
14  osx-arm64                              0x1026d9220 0x102688000 + 332320
15  osx-arm64                              0x102710364 0x102688000 + 557924
16  osx-arm64                              0x10269aa8c 0x102688000 + 76428
17  osx-arm64                              0x1026d9220 0x102688000 + 332320
18  osx-arm64                              0x1026dcd18 0x102688000 + 347416
19  osx-arm64                              0x10269bc4c 0x102688000 + 80972
20  osx-arm64                              0x1026a3fe8 0x102688000 + 114664
21  osx-arm64                              0x10269aa8c 0x102688000 + 76428
22  osx-arm64                              0x10269b354 0x102688000 + 78676
23  osx-arm64                              0x10269bec4 0x102688000 + 81604
24  osx-arm64                              0x1026a22ec 0x102688000 + 107244
25  osx-arm64                              0x10269aa8c 0x102688000 + 76428
26  osx-arm64                              0x1026d9220 0x102688000 + 332320
27  osx-arm64                              0x1026dcd18 0x102688000 + 347416
28  osx-arm64                              0x10269bc4c 0x102688000 + 80972
29  osx-arm64                              0x1026a1b18 0x102688000 + 105240
30  osx-arm64                              0x10269aa8c 0x102688000 + 76428
31  osx-arm64                              0x1026d9220 0x102688000 + 332320
32  osx-arm64                              0x1026dcd18 0x102688000 + 347416
33  osx-arm64                              0x10269bc4c 0x102688000 + 80972
34  bro3nABr                               0x1029716c4 Tbcload_EvalObjCmd + 608
35  osx-arm64                              0x10269aa8c 0x102688000 + 76428
36  osx-arm64                              0x10269b354 0x102688000 + 78676
37  osx-arm64                              0x1026f65f8 0x102688000 + 452088
38  osx-arm64                              0x1026a9c34 0x102688000 + 138292
39  osx-arm64                              0x10269aa8c 0x102688000 + 76428
40  osx-arm64                              0x1026d9220 0x102688000 + 332320
41  osx-arm64                              0x1026dcd18 0x102688000 + 347416
42  osx-arm64                              0x10269bc4c 0x102688000 + 80972
43  osx-arm64                              0x1026a1b18 0x102688000 + 105240
44  osx-arm64                              0x10269aa8c 0x102688000 + 76428
45  osx-arm64                              0x10269b354 0x102688000 + 78676
46  osx-arm64                              0x1026f65f8 0x102688000 + 452088
47  osx-arm64                              0x1026fc3b0 0x102688000 + 476080
48  osx-arm64                              0x10268da18 0x102688000 + 23064
49  dyld                                   0x102aa10f4 start + 520

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x181638010 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18160bd38 __select + 8
1   osx-arm64                              0x1027355f0 0x102688000 + 710128
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18163d240 _pthread_start + 148
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x181638024 thread_start + 8

Thread 3:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x181601954 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x181601d00 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x181708ed8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x181707390 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x181706734 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   AppKit                                 0x1843c9fb0 _NSEventThread + 196
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18163d240 _pthread_start + 148
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x181638024 thread_start + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x181638010 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x181638010 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000008   x1: 0x0000000000000001   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000600003db2580   x5: 0x0000000000000080   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000600003db2500
    x8: 0x0000000000000020   x9: 0x0000000000000103  x10: 0x0000000000000d80  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000083c2b892  x13: 0x0000000003c2b800  x14: 0x0000000003c00000  x15: 0x00000001da7738f0
   x16: 0x0000000000000209  x17: 0x00000001dbe6cf50  x18: 0x0000000149f03940  x19: 0x0000000000000080
   x20: 0x0000600003db2580  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x0000000000000008  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000600001dd1d10  x27: 0x00000001cbbb7676
   x28: 0x00000001cbc2b49d   fp: 0x000000016d775530   lr: 0x000000018162e864
    sp: 0x000000016d7754f0   pc: 0x000000018162beb8 cpsr: 0x40001000
   far: 0x00000001054b8140  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
       0x181600000 -        0x181635fff libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <384945e6-dd71-37e5-9a3d-84fff14a1e60> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x1814c2000 -        0x1814fdfff libobjc.A.dylib (*) <2eb32e1d-90cb-3256-8681-9034085a06a6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
       0x181684000 -        0x181bc7fff com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9) <35473de6-c433-332c-aee0-013fd5f6d4fd> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
       0x182578000 -        0x182965fff com.apple.Foundation (6.9) <f3ab29ba-726d-3d0b-8125-ceb1a79cd832> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
       0x18421b000 -        0x1850d1fff com.apple.AppKit (6.9) <8701760d-31b6-37eb-be77-ffb39921dd22> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
       0x107b48000 -        0x108283fff brQEBbHK (*) <5821bb84-4efc-357d-b5ed-ffadda5aa2ca> /private/tmp/brQEBbHK
       0x102688000 -        0x10278ffff osx-arm64 (*) <29eff3e8-3ba6-3315-b9ac-0dbe914842d3> /Users/USER/Desktop/postgresql-14.2-1-osx.app/Contents/MacOS/osx-arm64
       0x102970000 -        0x102973fff bro3nABr (*) <99e48406-4071-35f4-be8e-5a7f270b1722> /private/tmp/bro3nABr
       0x102a9c000 -        0x102afbfff dyld (*) <d21a73ea-79cd-36eb-8ac9-2c5cf5181a27> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x181636000 -        0x181642fff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <f7b2eccf-e6f1-3109-ae81-9028c0b8332a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=799.3M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=799.3M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=1.6G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.6G(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework               128K        1 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CG backing stores                 4032K        4 
CG image                            48K        2 
ColorSync                          608K       27 
CoreAnimation                     11.7M       11 
CoreGraphics                        32K        2 
CoreUI image data                 1456K       10 
Foundation                          16K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 
MALLOC                           365.3M       59 
MALLOC guard page                  192K       10 
MALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         816.0M        7         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
MALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                       56.1M        6 
Stack                             10.2M        6 
VM_ALLOCATE                        1.0G       10 
__AUTH                            1799K      159 
__AUTH_CONST                      9852K      311 
__DATA                            8628K      306 
__DATA_CONST                      10.5M      324 
__DATA_DIRTY                       596K      101 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       576.7M       15 
__OBJC_CONST                      1265K      127 
__OBJC_RO                         82.1M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         3104K        1 
__TEXT                           222.6M      339 
__UNICODE                          588K        1 
dyld private memory               1024K        1 
mapped file                      154.3M       24 
shared memory                      912K       15 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              3.7G     1885 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     2.5G     1885 



-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"osx-arm64","timestamp":"2022-03-06 10:44:49.00 +0800","app_version":"","slice_uuid":"29eff3e8-3ba6-3315-b9ac-0dbe914842d3","build_version":"","platform":1,"share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":1,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.2.1 (21D62)","incident_id":"007166A7-059B-402F-83A5-E40C33435B6C","name":"osx-arm64"}
{
  "uptime" : 4000,
  "procLaunch" : "2022-03-06 10:43:22.0452 +0800",
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 0,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookPro18,1",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 94573487629,
  "coalitionID" : 1099,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 12.2.1",
    "build" : "21D62",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2022-03-06 10:44:49.1961 +0800",
  "incident" : "007166A7-059B-402F-83A5-E40C33435B6C",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 1169,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 96664955727,
  "translated" : false,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "procName" : "osx-arm64",
  "procPath" : "\/Users\/USER\/Desktop\/postgresql-14.2-1-osx.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/osx-arm64",
  "parentProc" : "Exited process",
  "parentPid" : 1166,
  "coalitionName" : "com.installbuilder.appinstaller",
  "crashReporterKey" : "BF349008-4102-6C36-452E-5020959FA44F",
  "responsiblePid" : 1156,
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "termination" : {"namespace":"OBJC","flags":646,"code":1},
  "asi" : {"libobjc.A.dylib":["Invalid or prematurely-freed autorelease pool 0x1431880a8."]},
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":28807,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":8},{"value":1},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":105553180960128},{"value":128},{"value":0},{"value":105553180960000},{"value":32},{"value":259},{"value":3456},{"value":0},{"value":2210576530},{"value":63092736},{"value":62914560},{"value":7960213744,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoreleasePool"},{"value":521},{"value":7984303952},{"value":5535447360},{"value":128},{"value":105553180960128},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":8},{"value":0},{"value":105553147534608},{"value":7713027702,"objc-selector":"distantFuture"},{"value":7713502365,"objc-selector":"nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:"}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":6465710180},"cpsr":{"value":1073745920},"fp":{"value":6131504432},"sp":{"value":6131504368},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":6465699512,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":4383801664}},"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":179896,"symbol":"__abort_with_payload","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":190564,"symbol":"abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal","symbolLocation":104,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":190460,"symbol":"abort_with_reason","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":179548,"symbol":"_objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*)","symbolLocation":120,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":179428,"symbol":"_objc_fatal(char const*, ...)","symbolLocation":44,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":182504,"symbol":"AutoreleasePoolPage::badPop(void*)","symbolLocation":212,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":270328,"symbol":"_CFAutoreleasePoolPop","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":217836,"symbol":"-[NSAutoreleasePool drain]","symbolLocation":140,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":207336,"symbol":"-[NSApplication run]","symbolLocation":648,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":2960028,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":1019608,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":3291540,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":32968,"symbol":"RunQAppCmd","symbolLocation":92,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":76428,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":332320,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":557924,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":76428,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":332320,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":347416,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":80972,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":114664,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":76428,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":78676,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":81604,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":107244,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":76428,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":332320,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":347416,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":80972,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":105240,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":76428,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":332320,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":347416,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":80972,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":5828,"symbol":"Tbcload_EvalObjCmd","symbolLocation":608,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":76428,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":78676,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":452088,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":138292,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":76428,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":332320,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":347416,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":80972,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":105240,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":76428,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":78676,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":452088,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":476080,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":23064,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":20724,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":520,"imageIndex":8}]},{"id":28808,"frames":[{"imageOffset":8208,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":9}]},{"id":28846,"frames":[{"imageOffset":48440,"symbol":"__select","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":710128,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":29248,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":8228,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":9}]},{"id":28903,"name":"com.apple.NSEventThread","frames":[{"imageOffset":6484,"symbol":"mach_msg_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":7424,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":544472,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":372,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":537488,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1212,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":534324,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":600,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":1765296,"symbol":"_NSEventThread","symbolLocation":196,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":29248,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":8228,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":9}]},{"id":28912,"frames":[{"imageOffset":8208,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":9}]},{"id":29193,"frames":[{"imageOffset":8208,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":9}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6465519616,
    "size" : 221184,
    "uuid" : "384945e6-dd71-37e5-9a3d-84fff14a1e60",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6464217088,
    "size" : 245760,
    "uuid" : "2eb32e1d-90cb-3256-8681-9034085a06a6",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/libobjc.A.dylib",
    "name" : "libobjc.A.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6466060288,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "6.9",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.CoreFoundation",
    "size" : 5521408,
    "uuid" : "35473de6-c433-332c-aee0-013fd5f6d4fd",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CoreFoundation.framework\/Versions\/A\/CoreFoundation",
    "name" : "CoreFoundation",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "1856.107"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6481739776,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "6.9",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.Foundation",
    "size" : 4120576,
    "uuid" : "f3ab29ba-726d-3d0b-8125-ceb1a79cd832",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/Foundation.framework\/Versions\/C\/Foundation",
    "name" : "Foundation",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "1856.107"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6511767552,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "6.9",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.AppKit",
    "size" : 15429632,
    "uuid" : "8701760d-31b6-37eb-be77-ffb39921dd22",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/AppKit.framework\/Versions\/C\/AppKit",
    "name" : "AppKit",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "2113.30.116"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4424237056,
    "size" : 7585792,
    "uuid" : "5821bb84-4efc-357d-b5ed-ffadda5aa2ca",
    "path" : "\/private\/tmp\/brQEBbHK",
    "name" : "brQEBbHK"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4335370240,
    "size" : 1081344,
    "uuid" : "29eff3e8-3ba6-3315-b9ac-0dbe914842d3",
    "path" : "\/Users\/USER\/Desktop\/postgresql-14.2-1-osx.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/osx-arm64",
    "name" : "osx-arm64"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4338417664,
    "size" : 16384,
    "uuid" : "99e48406-4071-35f4-be8e-5a7f270b1722",
    "path" : "\/private\/tmp\/bro3nABr",
    "name" : "bro3nABr"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 4339646464,
    "size" : 393216,
    "uuid" : "d21a73ea-79cd-36eb-8ac9-2c5cf5181a27",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6465740800,
    "size" : 53248,
    "uuid" : "f7b2eccf-e6f1-3109-ae81-9028c0b8332a",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 6462570496,
  "size" : 3091218432,
  "uuid" : "296eb28e-6aeb-3129-8fa6-feb92261a4eb"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=799.3M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=799.3M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=1.6G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.6G(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nAccelerate framework               128K        1 \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nCG backing stores                 4032K        4 \nCG image                            48K        2 \nColorSync                          608K       27 \nCoreAnimation                     11.7M       11 \nCoreGraphics                        32K        2 \nCoreUI image data                 1456K       10 \nFoundation                          16K        1 \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                           365.3M       59 \nMALLOC guard page                  192K       10 \nMALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         816.0M        7         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\nMALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\nSTACK GUARD                       56.1M        6 \nStack                             10.2M        6 \nVM_ALLOCATE                        1.0G       10 \n__AUTH                            1799K      159 \n__AUTH_CONST                      9852K      311 \n__DATA                            8628K      306 \n__DATA_CONST                      10.5M      324 \n__DATA_DIRTY                       596K      101 \n__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       576.7M       15 \n__OBJC_CONST                      1265K      127 \n__OBJC_RO                         82.1M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         3104K        1 \n__TEXT                           222.6M      339 \n__UNICODE                          588K        1 \ndyld private memory               1024K        1 \nmapped file                      154.3M       24 \nshared memory                      912K       15 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              3.7G     1885 \nTOTAL, minus reserved VM space     2.5G     1885 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "queue" : "com.apple.main-thread"
  }
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "601d9415f79519000ccd4b69",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_TEXT_TO_SPEECH" : "621d4d11f441df278b2334c9"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000409
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5fc94383418129005b4e9ae0",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000263
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5ffde50ce2aacd000d47a95f",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000115
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "602ad4dac86151000cf27e46",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_DICTATION_ASSETS" : "61fb0e87c773c43cde3bb80e"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000305
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60da5e84ab0ca017dace9abf",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000008
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "607844aa04477260f58a8077",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_MORPHUN_ASSETS" : "6103050cbfe6dc472e1c982a"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000066
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
}
}

Model: MacBookPro18,1, BootROM 7429.81.3, proc 10:8:2 processors, 32 GB, SMC 
Graphics: Apple M1 Pro, Apple M1 Pro, Built-In
Display: Color LCD, 3456 x 2234 Retina, Main, MirrorOff, Online
Memory Module: LPDDR5
AirPort: Wi-Fi, wl0: Dec 13 2021 17:12:34 version 20.10.853.31.8.7.109 FWID 01-804e92d8
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB31Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the [Interactive Downloader by EDB](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads), I used [Postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com/) and everything seems to be working as per normal on my PgAdmin 4 now.

Doesn't entirely solve the issue but the above question is no longer a blocker to run DBs on PgAdmin as Postgres.app works just fine on my Macbook with specs defined above in the question.